# Read from text file one character at a time

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to convert characters in a text file based one what type they are:

Letters > L

Numbers > #

Is there a way to iterate through a file on a per-character basis? The only way I can get it to work currently is nested loops iterating through individual lines within the file. If there's a simpler way, that cuts out a lot of code I'll have to wade through.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You can use `Get-Content -Encoding Byte` and convert from the byte value back to a character:

   ```
   Get-Content foo.txt -Encoding Byte | foreach { [char]$_ }
   ```
2. You can use `Get-Content -Raw` and cast the result to `[byte[]]`. Not recommended for large files.

Both options above will give you all characters, including line breaks. Option 1 will not work with Unicode for obvious reasons; option 2 will.

Then there is the variant you mention already: Iterate twice, once by lines, once by character:

```
Get-Content foo.txt | foreach { [char[]] $_ | foreach { ... } }
```

If you don't need line breaks as characters I'd prefer this version since it should have reasonable runtime and memory requirements (e.g. it won't try to fit the whole file into memory).

Answer (score 4):

```
get-content myfile.txt | foreach { $_.ToCharArray() }
```

This flattens the contents of your file into a long array of characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you are processing very large files, the fastest (programmatic) method I have found is to use .NET `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`.  Utilizing these objects will allow you to read line-at-a-time into a string, perform manipulation, and then write to a new file line-at-a-time.  At the end, delete your original and rename the new file accordingly.

If you don't need to programmatically solve this and can utilize regular expressions, I recommend UltraEdit.  I don't know what wizardry they utilize, but it is MUCH faster at reading files than what I've managed to do in PowerShell.